# Apache vhost_alias

Tags: apache2, mod-vhost-alias

I have a question about vhost_alias

I got it working, it does the following job:

vhost.subdomain.domain.com -> sends to /var/www/vhost

using virtualdocumentroot and %1

But I don't like that I can access the same content also like this

vhost.vhost.subdomain.domain.com

since I have ServerAlias to *.subdomain.domain.com

How can I force that only vhost.subdomain.domain.com works?

The aim is to have many vhosts like this, for exmaple vhost1, vhost2, etc.

Thanks,
David

Comment: Do not set a wildcard alias if you don't want that behaviour.

Comment: OK, but what should I put in ServerAlias? Thanks

Comment: You don't have to specify a ServerAlias if you do not need one. That is the case if you want your server to be only reachable under vhost.subdomain.domain.com

Comment: I have both ServerName and ServerAlias set, ServerName is default.subdomain.domain.com and ServerAlias is *.subdomain.domain.com because I need this vhost to accept vhost1.subdomain.domain.com, vhost2.subdomain.domain.com, etc. Can I do that better way? Thanks

Comment: Okay, I see your problem now. I would suggest to configure your DNS server in a way that it will not redirect *.vhostX.subdomain.domain.com to your server but only *.subdomain.domain.com

Comment: I'm interested in solution at "Apache level" but thank you very much for your time.

Comment: Well, you could then try to set another vhost with ServerAlias *.*.subdomain.domain.com. It should catch the second level subdomains. However, the vhost order in your config is important then.

Answer (score 0):

One solution you could try is to add a fixed subdomain in your ServerAlias, before your actual dynamic subdomain:

Example:

```
ServerAlias www.*.subdomain.domain.com
```

This will ensure that

```
vhost.vhost.subdomain.domain.com
```

does not redirect, however, you will be forced to always add www. before your name.